# Mistura de CLASS e ID em HTML e CSS

Tags: html, css, html5

Fiz a prova do concurso do IFSULDESTE de Minas Gerais organizada pela Fundação CEFET-MG e estou com dúvidas na seguinte questão:

8 - Considere o código da página HTML a seguir.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É correto afirmar que a cor do texto do elemento `<strong>` do código acima é
a) red.
b) gray.
c) rebeccapurple.
d) darkgoldenrod.
e) cornfl owerblue.

Por que, segundo o gabarito, a letra E é a opção correta? Não entendi essa mistura de CLASS e ID. Marquei a letra A.

Fonte: Fundação CEFET. Disponível em: https://concurso.fundacaocefetminas.org.br/documentos/InformticaBomSucesso41637000719030930238.pdf. Acesso em: 31 jul 2019.

Comment: Não diz. Penso que seja o strong, mas vc tem razão, deveria ter especificado. Posso entrar com recurso.

Comment: @Vitor Carnaval, vc editou a questão especificando o elemento strong, mas a questão original não diz.

Comment: Pelo link que passou diz sim, elemento **strong**

Comment: Ah sim, tem razão

Comment: A opção C e a opção E tem o mesmo peso, mas a opção é ganha simplesmente pq é a regra que vem por último. Se vc colocar o CSS da letra C depois da letra E vc vai ver que é ele que fica valendo.

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste artigo: https://medium.com/emanuelg-blog/entendendo-a-preced%C3%AAncia-de-estilo-em-css-especificidade-heran%C3%A7a-e-efeito-cascata-a437c4929173

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta correta é a alternativa "E" mesmo. No `CSS`, quando se usa `#` na frente, é porque está utilizando `Id`, e não classe. Nesse caso ele está usando o `Id` "pai", e o `Id` "filho", tornando o atributo específico, e quanto mais específico ele for, mas "forte" ele será em relação aos outros, sendo assim, ele tem importância maior do que os outros atributos.

Answer (score 1):

CLASS e ID são coisas diferentes. ID é único por página, CLASS pode ter vários. Foi misturados vários justamente para confundir, pois se trata de uma prova. E um código sobrescreve o outro. Todos funcionaria, se só existisse somente 1 dos códigos CSS. (Claro que BODY iria colocar cor para tudo, e as outras funções somente para o id="sid").

Então o único motivo de aparecer vários assim é por se tratar de uma prova, pois somente 1 deles já funcionaria.